# How to delete nc files based on 'bad flag' attribute in python

Tags: python, attributes, delete-file

I have multiple nc files (4663 nc files) in a directory and I want to delete files based on a certain attribute.

The attribute name is 'bad', if bad=0 (0 type is a str) it means that the nc file contains correct information and it is not empty. And if bad=1 (1 type is numpy.float64) the nc file is empty.

I want to keep files with bad=0 and remove the rest.
here is the code I used, which remove all empty nc files (bad=1) in the path!:

```
import glob
import os
for file in glob.glob("path_to_files/*_nc"): # find all nc files
    if not ncfile.getncattr==1:
        os.remove(file)  # if file contains bad=1, delete it
```

here is the other approach which also gives similar answer and remove all files:

```
import os, glob
files = [file for file in glob.glob("path_to_files/*_nc") if not ncfile.getncattr('bad')==1]
for file in files:
    os.remove(file)
```

Here the ncdump -h nc file:

```
// global attributes:
:inverter = "OASIS ION-free 1DVAR" ;
:source_code_version = "2.2" ;
:bad = "0" ;
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: What is an "nc file"?

Comment: Nc files are a format of file for save climate data in multi-dimensions and the user can view each element of dimensions such as Lat, Lon, Level, Time, or...

Answer (score 0):

Apologies I cannot comment as I don't have enough points.

I believe you must interact with the NC files using a library such as NetCDF4 Python.

Try taking a look at this http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/

Comment: I used vn = nc.MFDataset('data_y*.nc') to read multiple file but I got this error: 'master dataset does not have a aggregation dimension,' and I stoped in the initial step! then os and glob works better than the xarray and NetCDF